# How does Date class know when to create a Standard Time or Daylight Time?

Tags: javascript

I ran into an issue when I create a Date like in the screenshot, one of them returns an object in Daylight Time, and the other returns in Standard Time.

It throws off D3 domain calculation.

Does any one know why?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: The dates for daylight savings can be easily calculated, so I guess it just does whatever is appropriate for the given date.

Comment: The Date will reflect the host system time zone configuration. Ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the answer to this - because one of the date is in Daylight Time period, so it returns as a Daylight Time